# MySQL connection taking time to open

Tags: php, mysql

I am using MySQL on wamp server. It takes 0.6 secs to establish a connection with mysql database, however when I use persistence connection it takes 0.035 secs. I read people comments on php manual and found that mysql_pconnect runs out of connections soon. Any suggestion how to improve connectivity time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way it should take 0.6 seconds.  Slow connection time is almost always related to [DNS lookups](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/dns.html).

Try starting your MySQL Server with [`skip_name_resolve`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-name-resolve) option enabled in your `my.ini` file.

---

Re your comments that you cannot connect:  It's hard to guess the reason for this because there are so many reasons for a connection failure.

- *Error 1045 Access denied:*  See [Causes of Access-Denied Errors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/access-denied.html).  You may have GRANTed privilegs to a mysql user in such a way that doesn't enable that user when connecting via localhost/127.0.0.1.
- *Error 2003 Can't connect to MySQL server:*  See [Can't connect to [local] MySQL server](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html) or the article on the [MySQL Forge: Error2003-CantConnectToMySQLServer](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Error2003-CantConnectToMySQLServer)

There are other connection troubleshooting steps, but they depend on the nature of the failure.  Can you be more specific about what error message you're getting?

Comment: MySQL started fine but now i can not connect to database. I put it under mysqld option

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/15073/remote-connection-to-mysql-server-takes-very-long

Comment: I did exactly that mysql started fine  but my script is unable to connect with database. I used 127.0.0.1 and localhost none of them is working. MySQL is on same machine.

Comment: I just figured out it says access denied for user odbc@127.0.0.1, wondering why odbc instead root?

Comment: On Windows, the MySQL client assumes "odbc" as a default user if you don't specify any user.

Comment: I changed the host to ALL for the root user and it worked fine. But the issue is still same, it takes 0.5 secs to establish a connection with database :(

Comment: 2 years later you saved my day!! :)